# jQuery load function after all other AJAX calls are complete

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have jQuery `.each` loop going through an array.  For each item in the array it is doing an AJAX call.  When all the AJAX calls are complete, I want to reload part of the page using the `.load()` method.  However this creates an endless loop if I use the `.ajaxStop()` method.

How can I achieve this?

Code below...

This is the part for when the button is clicked

```
$.each(remMems, function( index, value ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'components/update_members.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'memberbadge':value, 'function':'removemember'},
            timeout: 6000
        });  //end ajax call

        //if its the last item, then refresh the area 
        if (index == lastitem) {
            refreshMembers();
        }
    }); //end the for each loop
```

And this is the method/function called when the each loop is complete, to refresh the section of the page

```
function refreshMembers() {
    $('#listwrapper').load('members.php' +  ' #ert_members');
};
```

Comment: Are you using timeout as a way to ensure to the ajax call completes?

Comment: i would, but i don't know how long it might take...it could take 500 milliseconds or it could take 10 seconds (or possibly longer).
So i wish there was a way to look and test if all ajax calls are complete or at least a specific set.  something like

    if (ajaxComplete==true) {
        //do something
    }
I could be completely missing something though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your loop to create an array of deferred objects. You can then apply that array to `$.when` and call the `load()` method. Try this:

```
var requests = [];
$.each(remMems, function(index, value) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        url: 'components/update_members.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'memberbadge': value, 
            'function': 'removemember'
        },
        timeout: 6000
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    $('#listwrapper').load('members.php #ert_members');
});
```

Note that a better method entirely would be to modify your `update_members.php` to take an array of `value` and only make a single AJAX call.